# any ideas on how to solve matrix equation like this $X A_i Y = B_i$

Tags: matrices, functional-equations, matrix-equations, closed-form-expressions

the objective function is like

$$\operatorname*{argmin}_{X,Y} = \sum_i \|X A_i Y - B_i\|_F^2$$, and $A_i$ is a diagonal matrix

I've tried gradient-descent, but as it turns out not well, I wonder if there are any closed-form solutions. THX:)